# How to calculate facet using search:search?

Tags: marklogic

I need to do only facet calculations using search:search. does the return-results help?. If not, is there any other way (other than using cts:element-values)?

When the return-results option equal false, does the seach:search do the cts:search query?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you enable `return-facets`, and disable all other options including `return-results`, `search:search` (as well as `/v1/search`) will only calculate facets. For a full list of return options, and their default, see:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/query-options#id_97754

HTH!

Comment: Thank you. Even if I used the facets options like "frequency-order" as an example ?

Comment: Yes, facets are (normally) driven from in-memory lexicons that can sort by item or frequency without needing search results. Even if you apply search terms or other search constraints. These constraints are all resolved from indexes and lexicons, not from results themselves.